# npm run build without .cache folder in node_modules

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm

I am working on a Vue Application and when i am running a command npm run build to generate dist folder a new folder named as '.cache' is getting created in node_modules. This folder contain some files with very big names for e.g

**[ \.cache\terser-webpack-plugin\content-v2\sha512\4d\97\ 9f32457a91ce8f4c323456cfadsfsd2eif67db08gsdfgw54gfsf47yb595f34gsfdt54tf987b9b4gsde9gb170733bfe6aa3cd08e7bb0c150da5ca57446cb3f3iug2t ]**

Is there any way where we can reduce the size of the file name or we can create the .cache folder at some different location for E.g [C drive or D drive ]?

Is it possible npm run build command generate dist folder without creating .cache folder?

Comment: which bundler are you using? and is the '.cache' folder created in 'node_modules' or the root of your project?

Comment: .cache is created inside node_modules and node_modules is part root  project.

Comment: that shouldn't be a problem since node_modules should be local, unless you're tracking it in git

Comment: Actually we have added the vue build as part of full product build and because of file name is too big we are facing some issue. That's why i am thinking if we can reduce the file name or generate the .cache folder at some other location.
IF you can share thoughts on that it will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid populating the `.cache` folder you may use the following configuration in `vue.config.js`

```js
configureWebpack: config => 
{
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        cache: false, // either Boolean or String (does not work with Webpack 5 !!!)
        // cache: 'path/to/cache',
      }),
    ],
  },
},
chainWebpack: config =>
{
    config.module.rule('vue').use('vue-loader').loader('vue-loader').tap(options =>
    {
      delete options.cacheDirectory;
      return options;
    });
    config.module.rule('vue').uses.delete('cache-loader');
    config.module.rule('js').uses.delete('cache-loader');
}
```